# Error when specifying pathPrefix in AWS IAM ListGroup call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am running AWS IAM API calls through an application, and I'm running into an odd problem.

When I run the following GET call:

```
https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListGroups&MaxItems=10&Version=2010-05-08
```

I'm able to get a list of all my user groups successfully.

However, when I add PathPrefix to the GET call:

```
https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListGroups&PathPrefix=/&MaxItems=10&Version=2010-05-08
```

it returns the following error message:
"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."

Note that these are exactly the same calls being done in exactly the same way EXCEPT for the PathPrefix. I generate my AWS Signature in exactly the same way and I'm able to completely reproduce the issue just by removing the &PathPrefix=/ from the call.

I tried surrounding the PathPrefix in quotes '/' or double quotes "/", but then I get an error that the PathPrefix must start with / and only have alphanumeric characters or /.

The default for PathPrefix is /, so it should return everything. I'm trying to get this right before I start passing in non-default values for PathPrefix, which is my next step.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encoding the slash? Otherwise it may be interpreted as part of the url itself (since slashes are used in urls), not as a parameter value. Encoded slash should be %2F, so you could try:

```
&PathPrefix=%2F&MaxItems=10
```

[Here is](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) a reference that may help if I didn't get the encoding right.

Comment: I hadn't tried that yet! Unfortunately, it returns the same error "the request signature does not match the signature you provided"

Comment: Oh, ok well it may not accept the default / for some reason, since that would be the same as sending no value at all. I would try a "real" value for the prefix if that is your intent anyway.